# Rails destroy via Ajax thows js error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Okay so I'm building a really simple list with items app, pretty much exactly the same as your standard to-do list application. I've managed to ajax-ify the creation of new 'points' within a list (point `belongs_to :list` and list `has_many :points`) but I'm having trouble with the 'destroy' action.

When I click on the destroy link in the browser, nothing visibly occurs, and I get the error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /lists/10/points/125` obviously with different values depending on the id of the list and point.

If I refresh the page or look at the db, it's clear that the entry has indeed been deleted. Without ajax, my destroy action works just fine. I feel like I must be missing something obvious, any ideas?

fyi the 'pro' attribute is just a boolean associated with every point.

#### points_controller.rb

```
def destroy 
  @point = @list.points.find(params[:id])
  @point.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to list_url(@list) }
    format.js
  end
end
```

#### lists/show.html.erb

```
 <% @list.points.each do |point| %>
      <% if point.pro == true and point.valid? == true %>
        <li class="weight-<%= point.weight %>"><%= point.content %>
          <%= link_to "&times;".html_safe, [@list, point],  
                  :remote => true,
                  :method => :delete, 
                  :class=> "close", 
                  :data => {:dismiss => 'alert'} %>
    </li>
```

And it doesn't seem to matter what I put in **views/points/destroy.js.erb**, because the code doesn't seem to be getting executed.

### Update

I figured it out, I had to change the path in the delete link to `list_point_url(@list, point)`. The other problem was that my invalid javascript was causing a server error, so I didn't realize what the problem was (turns out `#<%= dom_id(@point) %>` needed to be wrapped in quotes).

Thanks all!

Comment: The problem may be in the view, because the controller code got executed So that the record was deleted.

Comment: Sounds like it's not rendering destroy.js.erb. Try `:format=>:js` or something to force the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check if the delete link routes to the `destroy` controller action, because `list_point_path` doesn't really seem like a delete route.

---

**Edit**

Sorry for the lake of knowledge but I'm not sure what `[@list, point]` will produce as a route. This is what I have for a view of my own, just for your reference:

```
link_to "Delete", admin_photo_path(photo), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Delete this image?", :class => "btn-trash"
```

My `admin_photo_path` is a singular path that route to a single `Photo` instance; not a collection.

**Edit**

Simple way could be sending delete to the point object, maybe this could help?

```
link_to "&times;".html_safe, point,  
              :remote => true,
              :method => :delete, 
              :class=> "close", 
              :data => {:dismiss => 'alert'}
```

Comment: I've since learned that I can simplify to just [@list, point] to specify route, as in `<%= link_to "&times;".html_safe, [@list, point], :remote => true, :method => :delete %>`

Comment: I've been using that format for generating paths throughout the views, and they all work, and it works without the ajax...

Comment: Okay, I think i know what [@list, point] will create as route. It will create something like list_point_path as URL. So in this scenario.  Point(s) belongs to List. so the delete could've been sent to list controller instead of point controller?

Comment: The example that just sends it to `point` returns `undefined method `point_path'`